# Automatic Active Class For Twitter Bootstrap Navigation in Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, laravel

Like most people, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for the site I'm currently developing in Laravel. So far I'm enjoying using Laravel as a PHP equivalent to Rails, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do the navigation bars. I'm attempting to make sure that my navbar `li` tags get the active class automatically, so I have this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
@if(URL::current() . "/" == URL::route('home'))
    <li class="active">
@else
    <li>
@endif
    <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
</li>
@if(URL::current() == URL::route('about'))
    <li class="active">
@else
    <li>
@endif
    <a href="{{ route('about') }}">About</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

This'll be fine, for now. But when I've got menus, and more navigations it'll end up looking awful to debug and deal with.

Is there anything akin to the Gem [Tabulous](https://github.com/techiferous/tabulous) for Laravel or a generally nicer way to deal with navigation in Laravel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [Bootstrapper](https://github.com/patricktalmadge/bootstrapper) package, it has lots of tools to help you with Twitter Bootstrap. In your example, you could build the navigation like this:

```
Navigation::pills(array(
    array(
        'label'  => 'Home',
        'url'    => URL::route('home'),
    ),
    array(
        'label'  => 'About',
        'url'    => URL::route('about'),
    )
));
```

There's also the shorthand method, less verbose, which I don't particularly like, but can be used:

```
Navigation::pills(
    Navigation::links(array(
        array('Home', URL::route('home')),
        array('About', URL::route('about')),
    ))
);
```

It's important to note that in both examples, **Bootstrapper takes care of the `active` class automatically**, comparing the current request URL against the one passed to the item. If, however, you wish to specify a different condition for this to apply, simply pass an `active` value, or a third value in the array, for the shorter method. Example:

```
Navigation::pills(array(
    array(
        'label'  => 'Home',
        'url'    => URL::route('home'),
    ),
    array(
        'label'  => 'About',
        'url'    => URL::route('about'),
        'active' => true,
    )
));
```

or

```
Navigation::pills(
    Navigation::links(array(
        array('Home', URL::route('home')),
        array('About', URL::route('about'), true),
    ))
);
```

Comment: Their doc is a bit out of date, but otherwise it works perfectly! Thanks much

Comment: It, it saddens me to see such an awesome project with outdated documentation. Still, it seems they're working to rebuild it from scratch, and we'll maybe see something cool soon.

Comment: It's tempting to offer to write the new docs for them. There's just minor things like constructors being different. I spent ages trying to get the navbar working because their docs say you should pass the type as the first argument, when it's actually expecting an array.

Answer (score 19):

I use this:

```
<li class="{{Request::path() == 'home' ? 'active' : '';}}">
  <a href="/home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple helper for this task. I saved it as */app/helpers/Menu.php*. Then in */app/start/global.php* I added my helper file to the `ClassLoader::addDirectories` array like so: `_app_path().'/helpers',` (if the class is not loaded try running "composer dump-autoload" in the console, more info about adding helpers [here](http://www.mackhankins.com/blog/laravel/defining-your-own-helper-classes-in-laravel-4))

```
class Menu {
 public static function item($route, $label='', $class='', $params=array()) {
    $class .= (Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction()['as']==$route) ? ' active' : '';
    $tag = $class ? '<li class="'.trim($class).'">' : '<li>';
    return $tag.HTML::link(URL::route($route, $params),$label).'</li>'; 
  }
}
```

In your view. just supply the route name and it will create a LI element with a link inside, the 'active' class is added to the LI element. You can also add custom classes by using the third parameter.

```
<ul class="menu">
  {{ Menu::item('index','Home') }}
  {{ Menu::item('pages.about','About Us') }}
  {{ Menu::item('pages.contact','Get In Touch','last') }}
  {{ Menu::item('profile-user','Profile','',array('username' => Auth::user()->username)) }}
</ul>
```

Comment: What if i need to pass yet another parameter as an array? For example, a link to see a user's profile. The original working link i have is: `<li><a href="{{ URL::route('profile-user', array('username' => Auth::user()->username)) }}">Profile</a></li>` In this case i get a Fatal Exception Error (E_PARSE): _syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' _

Comment: Yep, now it works! I use it like this: `{{ Menu::item('profile-user', 'Profile', 'active',array('username' => Auth::user()->username))}}`

Comment: I realized i had to save the class as Menu.php (with first letter as uppercase), otherwise, an error like class not found will appear when uploaded to server.

Comment: In case you want to add a bootstrap glyphicon in a certain menu link, you should use the `html_entity_decode()` function as follows: `{{ html_entity_decode(Menu::item('account-sign-in','<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log out')) }}`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading this who's on Laravel 5.4:

```
<li class="{{Request::path() == 'home' ? 'active' : '';}}">
```

Needs to become (take out the ending ;):

```
<li class="{{Request::path() == 'home' ? 'active' : ''}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wouldn't mind that the solution is jQuery based, then you could try something like:

```
$('#mainmenu li').removeClass('active');
$('#mainmenu li a[href="'+document.location.href+'"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
```

where `mainmenu` is the id of your navbar or any other element that contains the `li` items.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="{{ Request::is('about') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
<li class="{{ Request::is('contact') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another useful library could be here https://code.google.com/p/bootstrap-php/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FNavbar
Not complex, but very easy to use

```
$oNavbar      = new Bootstrap_Navbar_Handler(array('class' => 'nav-pills'));
$oNavbar->addEntry('Home', array('href' => '/pageurlHome'));
$oNavbar->addEntry('About', array('href' => '/pageurlAbout'));

$oNavbar->setAutoActive(true);
echo $oNavbar->display();
```

This generates:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav-pills nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/pageurlHome" class="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pageurlAbout" class="">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

by using

```
$oNavbar->setAutoActive();
```

the class automatically activates the corresponding entry

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Laravel solution, but a simple client side javascript solution I wrote today:

https://github.com/davidmars/bootstrapNavActive

```
<!--include our little script-->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidmars/bootstrapNavActive/master/BootstrapNavActive.min.js"></script>

<!--initialize the nav element-->
<script>
$( document ).ready(
function(){
    var $mySmartNav=$("#mySmartNav");
    new BootstrapNavActive($mySmartNav);
  }
);
</script>
```

Improvements on code are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

**I used this working fine**

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('blogs*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
   <a href="{{ route('blogs.create') }}">Create</a>
</li>
```