# Setting Bootstrap navbar active class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've been wondering around looking for solutions, but can't understand especially when creating helpers. I'm new in Laravel and I want a simple or if not a detailed instruction on how to set the active class for my bootstrap navbar.

Here's what I've done so far, but can't get it done:

```
<div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li class=""><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li {{ Request::is('about*') ? ' class="active"' : null }}><a href="{{ url('about') }}">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('auth/login') }}">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h2 class="">Tobacco Prevention and Control Program</h2>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Setting `class="active"` will make all nav-pills active. The intended effect is that only the `li` of the current page has the `active` class.

Comment: @krisdestruction The OP probably wants to render class="active" only on the current `nav li`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266909/automatic-active-class-for-twitter-bootstrap-navigation-in-laravel

Comment: @Ajoy Okay I was just in the review queue and it just looked like it needed more clarification, that's all

Comment: @krisdestruction The question is not clear for someone who hasn't dealt with a similar situation before. I'll edit it now

Comment: I have edited your question. Feel free to remove it or modify it with your own words!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li class="{{ Request::segment(1) === 'programs' ? 'active' : null }}">
                        <a href="{{ url('programs' )}}" ></i> Programs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{ Request::segment(1) === 'beneficiaries' ? 'active' : null }}">
                        <a href="{{url('beneficiaries')}}"> Beneficiaries</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{ Request::segment(1) === 'indicators' ? 'active' : null }}">
                        <a href="{{url('indicators')}}"> Indicators</a>
                    </li>                     
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 77):

If you are working with named routes. You can use this approach in your views:

```
{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('about') ? 'active' : '' }}
```

or

```
{{ Route::is('about') ? 'active' : '' }}
```

The `Illuminate\Routing\Router#is(...)` is an alias of the `Illuminate\Routing\Router#currentRouteNamed(...)`.

Comment: Best solution for when working with named routes indeed

Comment: I think is the best method if you using the named routes.

Comment: This work for my Laravel 7 blade template. I added to the class selector.
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children 
     {{ Route::currentRouteNamed('opportunities') ? 'current-menu-item' : '' }}">
      <a href="{{route('opportunities')}}">Business Opportunities</a>  </li>

Answer (score 68):

Your code is working fine, but you have to use it for every link that can be active. It is better to return only class name, not `class="..."` so you can add other classes.

Be careful when using `*` at the end (`about*`). If you use `/*` for home page then it will always be marked as active (because every other page starts with `/`).

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li class="{{ Request::is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="{{ Request::is('about') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ url('about') }}">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="{{ Request::is('auth/login') ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="{{ url('auth/login') }}">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can also move `{{ Request::is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}` to helper function/method.

Comment: What is the advantage of using `url("about")` for the `href` instead of just typing the path `/about`, which would be shorter?

Answer (score 14):

Throw this in your `helper.php`

```
function set_active($path, $active = 'active') {

    return call_user_func_array('Request::is', (array)$path) ? $active : '';

}
```

Use it like so

```
<li class="{{ set_active(['about*']) }}"><a href="{{ url('about') }}">About Us</a>
```

You can pass a single string to a route or multiple and wildcards.

See more detail on [Laravel Trick](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/setting-active-states-for-navigation)

Comment: I use a similar approach but what if I have a dynamic URL id like this.. /company/7431/departments. Here I need to somehow use $company->id to represent 7431. any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Set a section on your blade file (let home.blade.php) like

```
@section('Home', 'my-active-class')
```

And set a section on your another blade file (let about.blade.php) like

```
@section('About', 'my-active-class')
```

and yield this section on app.blade.php (Suppose you are extending from app.blade.php)

```
...
<li class="@yield('Home')"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="@yield('About')"><a href="#">About</a></li>
...
```

Answer (score 8):

`Request::path()` returns the request uri, for example: `http://localhost/programs` , will return `programs`, so you can do this:

```
 <li class="{{ Request::path() ==  'programs' ? 'active' : ''  }}">
                    <a href="{{ url('programs') }}"></i> Programs</a>
                </li>
```

Comment: Real solution. Especially for menus with dropdowns.

Answer (score 8):

### solution is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li class="{{ Request::is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}">
         <a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
     </li>
      <li class="{{ Request::is('about') ? 'active' : '' }}">
         <a href="{{ url('/about') }}">About Us</a>
     </li>
      <li class="{{ Request::is('whyus') ? 'active' : '' }}">
         <a href="{{ url('/whyus') }}">Why Us</a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is simple: to get your links to be active when using bootstrap, all you need is an if statement inside the class link, for instance: i have my current url as http://example.com/home

```
 <li class="{{ Request::url() == url('/home') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/home" ></li>
     Home
 </a>
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: `class="{{ Request::url() == url('/home') ? 'active' : '' }}"`

Answer (score 4):

The solution given by @Daniel Antos is best answer, as I have found. Mr. Danial Antos also warned about  using * at the end (about*). Because while using /* for home page then it is always marked as active (because every other page starts with /). So, I have used as follows and it worked fine for me:

```
{{ (Request::is('users') || Request::is('users/*') ? 'active open' : '') }}
```

Comment: I had to use dot * instead of /*, so users.*

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be simple, and it works for me.

```
<li class="{{ Request::segment(1)=='vehicles' ? 'active' : '' }}">
   <a href="/vehicles">Vehicles</a>
</li>
```

Comment: what about dynamic id like {{ Request::segment(1)=='vehicles.$id' ? 'active' : '' }}

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
composer require devmarketer/easynav
```

More details : https://github.com/DevMarketer/LaravelEasyNav

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li class={{ Request::is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}>
                        <a href="{{ url('programs' )}}" ></i> Programs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{ Request::segment(1) === 'beneficiaries' ? 'active' : null }}">
                        <a href="{{url('beneficiaries')}}"> Beneficiaries</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{ Request::segment(1) === 'indicators' ? 'active' : null }}">
                        <a href="{{url('indicators')}}"> Indicators</a>
                    </li>                     
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use
`Request::is('[level]') ? 'active' : ''` 
In case of multilevel, use:

`Request::is('[level]', '[level]/*') ? 'active' : ''`

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way is to add class active :-

```
@if (request()->routeIs('dashboard'))
   class="active"
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If we manage to get the URL path, we can compare it with the routes and put an active class there.

```
 {{'/'==request()->path()?'active':''}}

 {{'about'==request()->path()?'active':''}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple but fun and easy to use package named [Active](https://github.com/tuytoosh/active) which can solve your problem and maybe more...

I will be glad to see your comments.

Link of the package:

https://github.com/tuytoosh/active