# How to to mark actual element as an active

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have got a list (or menu) that contains many items.

Hierarchy looks like as follow:

- Topic

  - Subtopic

    - Subtopic_content
  - Subtopic

    - Subtopic_content
  - Subtopic

    - Subtopic_content

Route for **Subtopic** may look like:

```
route('subtopic',['topicid'=>$topic->id,'subtopicid'=>$subtopic->id])
```

Route for **Subtopic_content** may look like:

```
route('subtopic_content',['topicid'=>$topic->id,'subtopicid'=>$subtopic->id,'subtopic_content'=>$subtopic_content->id])
```

How to mark active element according to route as an active ?

I found example:

```
{{ Request::is( '/') ? 'active' : ''}}
```

But am looking for something like:

- in case of Subtopic  `{{ Request::is( 'subtopic',['topicid'=>$topic->id,'subtopicid'=>$subtopic->id]) ? 'active' : ''}}`
- in case of Subtopic_content 
  `{{ Request::is( 'subtopic_content',['topicid'=>$topic->id,'subtopicid'=>$subtopic->id,'subtopic_content'=>$subtopic_content->id]) ? 'active' : ''}}`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837555/setting-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-in-laravel-5 help you?

Comment: `Request::segment(1)` use segment to identify the each segment of the code and make it equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [hieu-le/active](https://packagist.org/packages/hieu-le/active) module.
How to use it: read in [Manual](https://www.hieule.info/products/laravel-active-version-3-released)

It solves your problem pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

On my project i created a MenuHelper

```
public static function setActiveMenu($array)
{
    Session::put('menu', json_encode($array));
}
```

on controller:

MenuHelper::setActiveMenu(['topic', 'subtopic']);

on menu view:

```
{{ Form::hidden('menu', Session::pull('menu')) }}
```

On template javascript

```
function setMenuActive() {
    var menu = $('input[name="menu"]').val();
    if (menu !== '') {
        menu = JSON.parse(menu);
    }

    if (menu.length === 1) {
        setMenuChild(0, menu);
    } else if (menu.length === 2) {
        setMenuParent(0, menu);
        setMenuChild(1, menu);
    } else if (menu.length > 2) {
        setMenuParent(0, menu);
        setMenuParent(1, menu);
        setMenuChild(2, menu);
    }
}

function setMenuParent(i, menu) {
    var $menuParent = $('#' + menu[i]);
    $menuParent.find('.bold').addClass('active');
    $menuParent.find('.collapsible-header').addClass('active');
    $menuParent.find('.collapsible-body').css('display', 'block');
}

function setMenuChild(i, menu) {
    $('#' + menu[i]).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to active your navbar or sidebar ul > li items don't go like that, instead use javascript's localStorage or sessionStorage which is really good and more convenient way to approach to your goal.
This technique used in [Gentelella](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/general_elements.html) too.
using php const you too many lines of code and too much headache

Here is the reference for [sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp) and here is the [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Here is my simple piece of code for you to get basic idea to activate a menu using sessionStorage which is a lot more better than writing php code

```
$('.sidebar__item > li ul a').click(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('active_menu', $(this).closest('.parent-menu').attr('id'));
});

document.getElementById(sessionStorage.getItem('active_menu')).click();
```