# Using CSS classes in Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

this is my first question, so i'm a bit nervous. I'm trying to learn Laravel and using 5.6 version. I got a HTML theme from themeforest.net and build a master layout. I include header and footer codes from another blade.php file. In header, there is a menu called 'Browse Categories'. On the home page the menu contains a CSS class that called 'show'. But on the other pages the menu shouldn't be in it. Here is my header.blade.php file

```html
<div class="col-md-5 order-3 order-md-2">
    <nav class="category-nav primary-nav show"><!--this is where i stuck-->
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="category-trigger">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Kategoriler
            </a>
            <ul class="category-menu">
                <li class="cat-item has-children">
                    <a href="#">Arts & Photography</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Bags & Cases</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Binoculars & Scopes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Digital Cameras</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Film Photography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lighting & Studio</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and that particular class is here

```css
.category-nav.show .category-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: visible;
}
```

I need the 'show' class passive except for the home page. how can I do that? My master layout is here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>@yield('title', config('app.name'))</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Use Minified Plugins Version For Fast Page Load -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/plugins.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="image/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
<div class="site-wrapper" id="top">

    @include('includes.header')

    @yield('content')

</div>
<!--=================================
    Footer Area
===================================== -->

    @include('includes.footer')

<!-- Use Minified Plugins Version For Fast Page Load -->
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax-mail.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can use laravel `{{ empty(request()->segment(1)) ? 'show' : '' }}` to display the class in homepage & not in other pages. Don't forget to do more research on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For named routes you can do as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33056239/11801683) like so:

```php
<a class="nav-link {{ Route::currentRouteNamed('home') ? 'active' : '' }}" href="#">
    Home
</a>
```

Or check the current route action if you don't use named routes

```php
<a class="nav-link {{ Route::currentRouteUses('App\Http\Controdllers\HomeController@index') ? 'active' : '' }}" href="#">
    Home
</a>
```

You can also not include the file at all:

```php
@if(Route::currentRouteUses('App\Http\Controdllers\HomeController@index'))
    @include('includes.header')
@endif
```

Or

```php
@if(Route::currentRouteNamed('home'))
    @include('includes.header')
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

When you render the homepage from your controller, include a variable like this:

```
return view('home', ['site' => 'home'])
```

then in your `home.blade.php`

```
<nav class="category-nav primary-nav @isset($site) show @endisset">
```

In your other views just don't include that variable.