# How to check if current url is valid in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**What I want to do**

laravel/routes/web.php

```php
Route::get('sample', 'SampleController@index');
```

In this case, http://localhost:8000/sample is valid.

But http://localhost:8000/test is not valid because it's not defined.

---

**Current Code**

```php
return \Route::current() ? true : false;
```

It doesn’t return null :

`\Route::current()` returns `\Illuminate\Routing\Route`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Bootstrap navbar active class in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837555/setting-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul Thanks. But it doesn't answer my question:(

Comment: where do you put the code in "current code" section? inside routes/web.php? Why do you want to determine whether it is valid?

Comment: @Anurat Chapanond I put the code in ApiController. I wanna return something different when its not valid.

Comment: @Take I still do not understand. If there is no route e.g. /test, how does your ApiController get called? It should show 404 not found page instead.

Comment: @Anurat Chapanond Yes that's true. But, in my case, when returning 404 page, it shows previous search history that is acquired in ApiController.

Answer (score 0):

```php
function isRoutePresent($urlToCheck)
{
    $available_url = [];
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        array_push($available_url, url($route->uri));
    }
    return in_array($urlToCheck, $available_url);
}
```

You can then call `isRoutePresent("http://localhost:8000/test")` to return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if a URI will match a registered route you can call `match` on the Route Collection:

```
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create('admin', 'get');

try {
    $match = Route::getRoutes()->match($request);
} catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e) {
    // no match
}
```

Though, not entirely sure what your intentions are.

Testing if the current route itself is valid doesn't make sense because for their to be a current route means it matched a route and it is valid. If a request was not valid then there would be a 404 returned or bad method exception.